# ArgumentCountError Too few arguments to function App\Controllers\Category::edit()

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

> ArgumentCountError
> Too few arguments to function App\Controllers\Category::edit(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\mylibrary\system\CodeIgniter.php on line 907 and exactly 1 expected

I'm trying to update the data, but when I include validation in it, an error occurs

Model

```
public function EditData($data)
{
    $this->db->table('category')
         ->where('category_id', $data['category_id'])
         ->update($data);
}
```

Controller

```
public function edit($category_id)
{
    $data = [
        'title' => 'Edit Data Kategori',
        'menu' => 'data',
        'submenu' => 'category',
        'validation' => \Config\Services::validation(),
        'category' => $this->categoryModel->getCategory($category_id)
    ];

    return view('/category/edit', $data);
}

public function update($category_id)
{
    if(!$this->validate([
        'category_id' => [
            'rules' => 'required',
            'errors' => [
                'required' => '{field} harus diisi.',
                'is_unique' => '{field} sudah terdaftar.'
            ]
        ]
    ] )) {
        return redirect()->to('/category/edit/' . 
                    $this->request->getVar('category_id'))
                ->withInput();
    }

    $data = [
        'category_id' => $category_id,
        'kategori' => $this->request->getPost('kategori')
    ];
    $this->categoryModel->EditData($data);
    session()->setFlashData('pesan', 'Data berhasil diubah');
    return redirect()->to('/category');
}
```

View

```
<form action="/Category/update/<?= $category['category_id'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <?= csrf_field(); ?>
                                   
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col col-md-3">
            <label for="kategori" class=" form-control-label">Kategori</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
            <input type="text" id="kategori" name="kategori" 
                    placeholder="Masukkan kategori" 
                    class="form-control <?= ($validation->hasError('category_id')) ? 'is-invalid' : '' ?>" 
                    autofocus value="<?= (old('kategori')) ? old('kategori') : $category['kategori'] ?>">
    
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                <?= $validation->getError('category_id'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <br>
    
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
            <a href="/Category" class="btn btn-success">Kembali</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The error complaints about you calling `edit($category_id)` without any argument (missing the category id). Where and how are you creating the links to the edit page that causes this issue when you follow them? Do you see the category id in the URL when you get this error?

Comment: Good code indentation and layout ___is for life, not just for Christmas___ and would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Could it be this: `redirect()->to('/category/edit/' . $this->request->getVar('category_id'))->withInput()` that is the problem? `$this->request->getVar('category_id')` is the same as: `$_REQUEST['category_id']`, but I don't see any form element or query parameter named `category_id`. Shouldn't it be `redirect()->to('/category/edit/' . $category_id)->withInput()` instead?

Comment: can You provide the model of **getCategory** from **categoryModel**. i hope i can help You to solve the problem.